Clean string column with messy data into numeric in polars
The following code has been given:

import polars as pl
import numpy as np

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)

# Define the sample size
n = 35000000

# Define the possible values
values_CRP = ["10", "2", "3", None, "<4", ">5"]
values_CRP2 = ["10", "12", "<5", "NA", ">5", "5"]
values_CRP3 = ["10", "12.3", "<5", "NA", ">5.5", "4"]

# Create the DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "CRP": np.random.choice(values_CRP, n, replace=True),
    "CRP2": np.random.choice(values_CRP2, n, replace=True),
    "CRP3": np.random.choice(values_CRP3, n, replace=True)
})


Assume that these are columns of 3 different biomarkers. I want to clean them by grabbing the numeric part of each string value, whenever the string does not start with "<" or ">" ("10" should give 10), leave the nulls as they are (meaning the patient did not have any measurement at that time point), and replace the values starting with "<" or ">" with the median of the values which fall below or above the second element of the respective value. For example, "<5" should be replaced with the median of observations with a biomarker value below 5. For ">5", we take observations above. If we have a value of ">10000", and there are no observations above 10000, then we null it. Same with <.
Desired output for minimal example:

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"Current":["<4","3", "2", None, ">5", "10"],
                   "Goal": [2.5,3,2,None,10,10]})


Ideally and because I have 11 columns in reality and almost 40 million rows, I would like to do as much as possible in lazy mode.

I think you would need to join dataframe on itself or run some kind of subquery, and for these task I find DuckDB to be very user-friendly:
df = df.with_columns(
    num = pl.col.Current.cast(pl.Float64, strict=False)
)

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        d.Current,
        d.Goal,
        case
            when d.Current[1] == '<' then
                (select median(tt.num) from df as tt where tt.num < try_cast(d.Current[2:] as float))
            when d.Current[1] == '>' then
                (select median(tt.num) from df as tt where tt.num > try_cast(d.Current[2:] as float))
            else d.num
        end as Calc
    from df as d
""").pl()

shape: (6, 3)
┌─────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Current ┆ Goal ┆ Calc │
│ ---     ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str     ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ <4      ┆ 2.5  ┆ 2.5  │
│ 3       ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
│ 2       ┆ 2.0  ┆ 2.0  │
│ null    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ >5      ┆ 10.0 ┆ 10.0 │
│ 10      ┆ 10.0 ┆ 10.0 │
└─────────┴──────┴──────┘

For pure polars you could probably precalculate median for all unique values first and then just join:
df_num = df.select(num = pl.col.Current.cast(pl.Float64, strict=False)).drop_nulls()
df_calc = (
    df
    .filter(pl.col.Current.str.head(1).is_in(["<",">"]))
    .select(
        pl.col.Current,
        oper = pl.col.Current.str.head(1),
        bound = pl.col.Current.str.tail(-1).cast(pl.Float64)
    )
    .unique()
)

df_mapping = (
    df_num
    .join(df_calc, how="cross")
    .filter(
        ((pl.col.oper == ">") & (pl.col.num > pl.col.bound)) |
        ((pl.col.oper == "<") & (pl.col.num < pl.col.bound))
    )
    .group_by("Current")
    .agg(pl.col.num.median())
)

(
    df
    .join(df_mapping, on="Current", how="left")
    .with_columns(pl.col.num.fill_null(pl.col.Current))
)

ape: (6, 3)
┌─────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Current ┆ Goal ┆ num  │
│ ---     ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str     ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ <4      ┆ 2.5  ┆ 2.5  │
│ 3       ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
│ 2       ┆ 2.0  ┆ 2.0  │
│ null    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ >5      ┆ 10.0 ┆ 10.0 │
│ 10      ┆ 10.0 ┆ 10.0 │
└─────────┴──────┴──────┘

If you want to extend it to multiple columns, you probably can do the same, but unpivot() your DataFrame first, calculate values and then pivot() it back again.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "CRP1":["<4","3", "2", None, ">5", "10"],
    "CRP2":["1","2", None, "3", "4", "<2"]
})

shape: (6, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ CRP1 ┆ CRP2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ <4   ┆ 1    │
│ 3    ┆ 2    │
│ 2    ┆ null │
│ null ┆ 3    │
│ >5   ┆ 4    │
│ 10   ┆ <2   │
└──────┴──────┘

df_unpivot = df.with_row_index().unpivot(index="index")

df_num = (
    df_unpivot
    .select(
        pl.col.variable,
        num = pl.col.value.cast(pl.Float64, strict=False)
    )
    .drop_nulls()
)

df_calc = (
    df_unpivot
    .filter(pl.col.value.str.head(1).is_in(["<",">"]))
    .select(
        pl.col.variable,
        pl.col.value,
        oper = pl.col.value.str.head(1),
        bound = pl.col.value.str.tail(-1).cast(pl.Float64)
    )
    .unique()
)

df_mapping = (
    df_calc
    .join(df_num, on="variable", how="inner")
    .filter(
        ((pl.col.oper == ">") & (pl.col.num > pl.col.bound)) |
        ((pl.col.oper == "<") & (pl.col.num < pl.col.bound))
    )
    .group_by("variable","value")
    .agg(pl.col.num.median())
)

(
    df_unpivot
    .join(df_mapping, on=["variable","value"], how="left")
    .with_columns(pl.col.num.fill_null(pl.col.value).cast(pl.Float64))
    .pivot("variable", index="index", values=["value","num"])
)

shape: (6, 5)
┌───────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ index ┆ value_CRP1 ┆ value_CRP2 ┆ num_CRP1 ┆ num_CRP2 │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ u32   ┆ str        ┆ str        ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ <4         ┆ 1          ┆ 2.5      ┆ 1.0      │
│ 1     ┆ 3          ┆ 2          ┆ 3.0      ┆ 2.0      │
│ 2     ┆ 2          ┆ null       ┆ 2.0      ┆ null     │
│ 3     ┆ null       ┆ 3          ┆ null     ┆ 3.0      │
│ 4     ┆ >5         ┆ 4          ┆ 10.0     ┆ 4.0      │
│ 5     ┆ 10         ┆ <2         ┆ 10.0     ┆ 1.0      │
└───────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴──────────┘


You are using information from pl.col.Goal which is not something we are going to have in the first place. As I wrote, the original dataframe is reported at the start of my question.

I don’t use Goal column i only left it here for comparison purposes

Apologies, it was just the fill_null at the end which confused me. I am going to try it soon in my data.

ah yes my fault, it should be Current of course, fixed

Any idea on how to apply your programming process for all my variables that demand this process?

It's possible to run it over variable colunms, but it would probably include unpivot which will further explode the size of your data set
if you have 11 columns maybe you can just run a loop over these columns and then combine results into a new DataFrame?

Can you display your try ? I am not familiar with python and I am mostly an R user.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
